# return statement inside applet method which is called from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, swing, servlets, applet

my scenario is like i invoke applet API from javascript whose return statement is boolean, but i unable to get boolean response from that method.

let me tell what happening inside that method

1. from js control is going to applet method abc()
2. inside abc() method i am invoking  servlet which is does some process at server end  and returns response which i am getting with out any issues.
3. after this i am doing some regular java stuff and trying to return true or false
4. I am not getting this response in javascript

Note: This points may be helpful to figure out the issue

1.My applet implements runnable interface which is used for show confirmation dialog to use developed using swing components, this code triggers in some scenarios not every.

2. I use servlets which returns json response
   Let me know if you need any details
3. I am using below function in foreach

   ```javascript
   function abc()
   {
     var status = printerApplet.startBulkPersoProcessing(a, b, c);
                       alert("Is it coming here:::");
                       alert(status);
    }
   ```

This status is not printed what ever we do.

Comment: please share how you are returning the response from applet to jaavascript

Comment: It is causing by for each i am trying to figure out how to  fix this.

Comment: please post some code here so that we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should make sure you declared your applet like the following :

```
<APPLET code="MyApplet.class" height="0" id="myApplet" name="myApplet"
                                    archive="/path/to/MyApplet.jar"></APPLET>
```

after that to call MyApplet from JS like the following :

```
function callMyAppletFromJS() {
            alert("callMyAppletFromJS");
                document.getElementById('myApplet').jsAppletCall();
      }
```

in your applet call the JS back like the following  :

```
public void jsAppletCall() {
      //       do you java stuff here 
      // then 
      // call the javascript from the applet using the JSOBject 
              JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
              win.eval("callJSFromMyAppletMessage();");
     }
```

and the JS  function to be called from the applet like the following :

```
function callJSFromMyAppletMessage() {
     alert("callJSFromMyAppletMessage");
      }
```

so  the way to call the JS from applet is using the **JSObject** , please check the docs [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/plugin2/liveconnect/jsobject-javadoc/netscape/javascript/JSObject.html) for the JSObject as it describes the use for this class .

also as @Hemant mentioned , please check the oracle tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html) about this subject .

**Note** : 
but please be aware if you are calling your applet from JS , even if its signed applet , it will be treated as unsigned applet , check the oracle docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) .

Hope that Helps .

Comment: Ya i agree with you. Thanks for your help my issue got solved. it was some code problem.

Comment: what was the problem ? , and accept the answer if its correct

Comment: Your explanation was very helpful thanks and i accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's JSObject to callback a JS function defined in your HTML view.

This is the one of the convenient way of handling async function calls.

More info on JSObject implementation...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html

Hope it helps!